# Use jquery $.ajax to construct WSDL envelope and make call

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, wsdl

I'm in the process of getting rid of webservice.htc from our front end (to remove the dependency on IE) and I'm replacing it with the jquery $.ajax call. I want to call a webservice defined in a WSDL file, as the old webservice.htc did quite well - it handled the SOAP envelope creation for us. I'm fairly new to SOAP/WSDL/Ajax so not sure of what's available out there to help me in this.

At the moment I have a proof of concept running, I've done this by hard-coding the WSDL envelope with the call name, parameters and parameter types (e.g. xsi:type="xsd:string"), etc. Now I'm looking to generalise the code (which is all javascript/jquery) such that it will handle all of our web services.

I was wondering if there was a jquery call or plug-in or other that would handle the creation of SOAP envelopes for me (given a valid WSDL file) so that I don't have to be concerned with constructing the SOAP XML envelope with the correct parameter types.

Comment: Does it have to be a soap request from javascript? For such cases i prefer to use a proxy script that translates the requests from json<->proxy<->webservice

Comment: Ideally yes, but we do have a web service proxy written in C#. Is it possible to interpret JSON in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a [soap-client plugin for jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/14709) but i haven't tried it yet

i usually build the soap-body by hand and send it using post or ajax

Comment: Yeah, I guess that cuts the mustard for most applications. I'm putting it into a system with ~700 existing service calls where I'm hoping I can just replace webservice.htc with similar functionality (i.e. SOAP envelope creation is automatic).

Comment: I voted up! Can you please help me too with this? I want to do the same. I want t write SOAP body and then send it over POST request.